# Access Router From Internet

Tags: dns, ip, webserver, router, dmz

I am aware of how to access my router under normal circumstances (simply entering your public IP address), however I have forwarded a few ports to a web server that I have setup.  Ports 22, 80, 8080 are all forwarded (for different reasons), and my public IP is set up through a DNS system.

Now when I attempt to access my router settings (through my public IP) it re-directs me to my website.  I tried entering:

```
PU:BL:IC:IP:8080
```

and

```
PU:BL:IC:IP:80
```

with no success.  I did attempt to disable my web server (which I still have access to) and that also failed.  Is there anyway around this without having to go home and change setting manually.  I have DMZ disabled if that's any help.

Comment: Please elaborate of why this is being down voted.

Comment: If port 22 is forwarded to an internal SSH server, can you SSH into your network and then run a browser from inside your network to access the router admin interface? Maybe you can use a text-mode browser from SSH, such as lynx or elinks, or if you have an X server running at your current location you can use SSH's X11 forwarding to run a graphical browser.

Comment: Actually, it might be easier to use SSH port forwarding to poke a hole through the router to access your router's admin interface right from the local computer. `ssh -L 12345:router-ip:80 public-ip`, and then go to http://localhost:12345/ in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have forwarded port 22, which is usually the SSH port. There are three ways to access your router from SSH:

- Use SSH port forwarding to poke a hole through the router to access you're router's admin interface from the local computer. To do this in OpenSSH from the command line, you would use the option `-L 12345:router-ip:80`. In PuTTY, you would use the Connection/SSH/Tunnels category to add a local forwarded port with source 12345 and destination router-ip:80. Then you can access your admin interface from your local machine by browsing to http://localhost:12345. If your router uses a different port than 80, change that in the examples above. If you want to use a different local port than 12345, you may change that as well.
- Use a text-mode browser, such as lynx or elinks, from the SSH connection. This is the simplest to set up, but using modern web apps in text-mode browsers can be difficult or impossible.
- If you have an X server running at your current location, use SSH's X11 forwarding to run a graphical browser. Use the `-X` option for OpenSSH at the command line, or check the X11 forwarding box in Connection/SSH/X11 in PuTTY.